# iphone SDK: How to check user set up a valid IP , Netmask , Router?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uitextfield, ip

It is simple to understand after this pic.

[image]

I add fewtextfields in tableview

I already set the keyboard style is number pad.

Now the problems is

**1.Do I need to create 12 textfields** ???ex. `UITextField *ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4....`or just set different tag for textfield ?

**2.How to check user enter wrong char not 3 valid numbers**

(even the keyboard is set number pad,but it might can paste words...)

**3.How to check user did follow this setting rules ???**

<1>If IP1 is 0~223 , IP2 need to be set 0~255,IP3,IP4 both are 0~255

<2>If IP1 is 172 ,IP2 is set 16~31.IP3,IP4 both are 0~255;
  If IP1 is 192 ,IP2 must be 168.IP3 IP4 are 0~255

<3>Netmask set default 255.255.255.0

<4>Router 0~223  ,0~255 ,0~255 ,0~255

This IP setting rules is my friends tech me this ...I not sure the rules is right or not?

**--------ADD---------**

Oh....Sorry , I need to add more information about is static IP

This static IP setting is set up for some hardware device ,ex IP cam

so it won't need to paste a URL

Comment: You could (or should?) derive the default Netmask from the IP address... E.g. whether it's a Class A, B, C or D address... Though depending on your actual use-case it may not be a good thing to do.

Comment: Let me search if I can find any information about it

Comment: @Romain no, you should _not_ do this.  "Classful" IP addressing was deprecated back in the early 90s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I despise programs that force me to type the components of an IP address into separate fields. It is awkward to type addresses in, and worst of all I can't paste IP addresses in or out. Just use a single field for each address, and validate what the user enters.

To validate manually, split the entry on `'.'` and test that each substring correctly converts to an integer in the range [0, 255]. You could check more precisely, but if the intent is to connect to an existing network, checking that the first component is < 224 won't help at all if the user incorrectly typed 213 instead of 123.

Comment: I know , but my boss he want me to separate fields ,I was set single field at first......

Comment: @WebberLai, You need to teach your boss, not the other way around ;-)

Comment: Tell your boss that not only is entering IP addresses into separate fields even more annoying on an iPhone (there is no tab key, and the very thought of copy-pasting or mentally transcribing one from another app makes me shudder), but Apple themselves don't do this. Show your boss how a static IP is set up via the Wi-Fi networks configuration.

Comment: Actually the despise can be mitigated or completely removed by adding some extra behavior on the fields: when user has entered three digits or types a dot, jump to next field. If user hits back and is in an empty field, jump to the previous one and erase one char.

Comment: @ Marcelo Contos the first time I use standard keyboard and use jump tag to tab textfields, but he want to using number pad...I have no way to do ...

Comment: @Romain: That doesn't help at all with copy-paste. The long and the short of it is that separate fields are worse than a single field. Why use complicated logic to mitigate a problem that can be completely solved by implementing a simpler model?

Comment: @WebberLai: You could add a `.` button to the number pad with [this trick](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key). But this is a waste of effort. Just give users a normal alpha keyboard – switched over to numeric mode, just like Apple does in the Wi-Fi settings – and be done with it. Anything more is over-complicating things.

Comment: @Marcelo: In some ways you're right, though you can also make it copy-paste friendly. Basically making the four fields feel like one single field. Now that complicated logic can be driven by user requirement (however unlikely that may seem to you, it still happens).

Comment: @Romain: I have no doubt that it can be done, but why? It doesn't make anything easier for anyone.

Comment: @Marcelo:I agree with you......after testing ,a wrong setting could send my device to a unknown space ~ and I can't using Bonjour to search it back.